# Is it possible to renice a subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, nice, renice

I know about [`os.nice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.nice) it works perfect for parent process, but I need to do renice of my child subprocesses. I found way to do this, but it seems to be not very handy and too excessive:

```
os.system("renice -n %d %d" % ( new_nice, suprocess.pid ) )
```

And it isn't return resulting nice level after renicing.

Is there more clean way to renice subprocesses in python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `preexec_fn` parameter of [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> If `preexec_fn` is set to a callable object, this object will be called in the child process just before the child is executed. (Unix only)

Example:

```
>>> Popen(["nice"]).communicate()
0
(None, None)
>>> Popen(["nice"], preexec_fn=lambda : os.nice(10)).communicate()
10
(None, None)
>>> Popen(["nice"], preexec_fn=lambda : os.nice(20)).communicate()
19
(None, None)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system`, so you can access any results printed to sys.stdout.  IIRC, `os.system` only gives you access to the return value, which is probably '0' and not the nice level.

Answer (score 2):

renice is usually implemented  by set/[getpriority](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/setpriority.html) , which doesn't seem to have made it into the python os or posix module(yet?). So calling the renice system command seems like your best bet now.

As an alternative, you could os.nice the parent before you create a child process - which will inherit its parents nice value - and os.nice back again after you've created the child process.

Comment: He could call setpriority/getpriority using ctypes.

Answer (score 1):

without proper rights you can renice only in one way

Answer (score 1):

I created a python script with a CLI in the past. You can find it here: https://github.com/jedie/python-code-snippets/blob/master/CodeSnippets/reniceall.py

Answer (score 1):

> renice is usually implemented by set/getpriority , which doesn't seem to have made it into the python os or posix module(yet?). So calling the renice system command seems like your best bet now.

Expanding Daniel's comment about `ctypes`:

```
from ctypes import cdll
libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")

for pid in pids:
    print("old priority for PID", pid, "is", libc.getpriority(0, pid))
    libc.setpriority(0, pid, 20)
    print("new priority for PID", pid, "is", libc.getpriority(0, pid))
```

Result:

```
old priority for PID 9721 is 0
new priority for PID 9721 is 19
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the nice of the subprocess without changing the parent, you can start a function which runs the subprocess command with the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) library.

```
import threading, subprocess

def run():
    os.nice(5)
    subprocess.run(['sha256sum', '/dev/urandom'])

thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
thread.start()
```