# Python UDP socket send bottleneck (slow/delays randomly)

Tags: python, sockets, gil

## Python UDP Streamer with hickup in sending

I'm currently developing on a python 3.4 network streaming app. And i have some crazy behavior with my socket. (Target 3.3 compatible if possible)
Definition: When i talk of Stream an UDP-Stream is meant.

> ### The problem
>
> While sending the socket.send operation sometimes start take 1-3ms, as i will describe more below the transfer target is much higher. I found other threads here telling about problems with speed, but they handled to send 200k packages a second, but they only send "A". In my case each packet is 1500 Bytes inc. UDP and IP header added by socket. 
>   Please see my explains below if the problem not is clear at this point.
>
> ### Question
>
> Does anyone have an idea why this delays? Or how to speed up sending to reach real time?

#### My test code looks like this:

```py
def _transfer(self):
    self.total_num_samps_sent = 0
    self.sequence_out = 0
    self.send_in_progress = True
    send = self.udp_socket.send
    for i in range(0, len(streams), 1):
        stream_data, stream_samps, stream_seq = self.packed_streams[i]
        # commit the samples
        start_try_send_time = monotonic()
        while not self.ready():
            if monotonic() - start_try_send_time > self.timeout > 0:
                # timeout; if timeout == 0 wait endless
                return 0
        self.sequence_out = stream_seq
        # ######################
        # Here is the bottleneck
        # ######################
        s = monotonic()
        send(stream_data)
        e = monotonic()
        if e-s > 0:
            print(str(i) + ': ' + str(e-s))
        # #####################
        # end measure monotonic
        # #####################
    self.total_num_samps_sent += stream_samps
    self.send_in_progress = False
```

> self.packed_streams contains a list of tuples (data_in_bytes(),  number_samples_in_this_stream, sequence_out) 
>   the function self.ready() returns True when the targed ACK'ed enough packets send (has free RAM).

The special marked bottleneck is more detailed profiled: see it a little more down

#### The socket creation looks like:

```py
self.target = (str(self.ip_target), port)
self.udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
self.udp_socket.settimeout(self.socket_timeout)
try:
    self.udp_socket.bind((str(self.ip_own), 0))
except OSError as os_error:
    error = ('OS Error: {0}'.format(os_error)
             + linesep + 'IP src: ' + str(self.ip_own)
             + linesep + 'IP dst: ' + str(self.ip_usrp)
             + linesep + 'Port: {0}'.format(port))
    exit(error)
self.udp_socket.connect(self.target)
# not helps to set to non blocking
# self.udp_socket.setblocking(False)
```

The sendfunction (1st code block) runs as seperate thread. 
And the UDPFlowControl spawns another thread too. Running on same socket as the send streamer (the Streamer inherits the FlowControl and uses its ready state)

#### UDPFlowControl

```py
def _worker(self):
    """
    * Receive Loop
    * - update flow control condition count
    * - put async message packets into queue
    """
    self.send_here_am_i()
    while 1:
        ready = select([self.udp_socket], [], [], self.socket_timeout)
        if ready[0]:
            try:
                data_in = self.udp_socket.recv(2048)
            except:
                # ignore timeout/error buffers
                continue
            # with suppress(Exception):  #ToDo Reenable after test is done
            bytes_in = len(data_in)
            self.data_received += bytes_in
            # extract the vrt header packet info
            vrt = VRTImplementation()
            vrt.num_packet_words32 = int(bytes_in / ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_uint32))
            if not vrt.unpack_header(data_in, VRTEndian.BIG_ENDIAN):
                continue
            # handle a tx async report message
            if vrt.stream_id32 == Defaults.ASYNC_SID and vrt.packet_type != PacketType.DATA:
                # fill in the async metadata
                metadata = MetadataAsync()
                metadata.load_from_vrt(vrt, data_in[vrt.num_header_words32 * 4:],
                                       self.tick_rate)
                # catch the flow control packets and react
                if metadata.event_code == EventCode.FLOW_CONTROL:
                    self.sequence_in = \
                        unpack('>I', data_in[vrt.num_header_words32 * 4 + 4:vrt.num_header_words32 * 4 + 8])[0]
                    continue
                self.async_msg_fifo.append(metadata)
            else:
                # TODO: unknown packet
                pass

def ready(self):
    """
    Check if less ack are outstanding than max allowed
    :returns bool: if device can get more data
    """
    return self.sequence_out - self.sequence_in < self.max_sequence_out
```

#### cProfile

> << Removed old benchmark >> see history if need this information again!

As mentioned above the monotonic profiling is the reason of my question. As you see times of 0 are ignored. The output looks like this: (The stream contains data of 5 seconds (2754,8 bytestreams to send) with resulting size (wireshark) of 1500 Bytes each

```
Send:  445.40K of    5.00M, Sending:  True @ monotonic time:   44927.0550
1227: 0.01599999999598367
1499: 0.01599999999598367
1740: 0.014999999999417923
1883: 0.01600000000325963
Send:  724.18K of    5.00M, Sending:  True @ monotonic time:   44927.3200
....
```

First number is the index of delayed packed. The 2nd number is the diff time monotonic of this delay. Not shown here but in my log i found timings like 7582: 0.030999999995401595 and sometimes much heigher at 0.06...

The lines starting with Send are the Main Thread writing the current state to console. After writing it goes sleep 250ms.

My problem is currently the system only runs at 1/25 of target speed and already started this hickups as you see in cProfile this takes nearly 30 seconds to send a 5 second stream. Target speed would be 68870P/s @ each 1500Bytes which is ~98,5MByte containing overhead @ GbE => 125MByte/s limit.

This is single target application. And normally attached directly to device over network-wire without any router,switch, whatever. So the network belongs to only this app and device.

What i have done so far:

- As you see in code i minimized the test to a minimum, the streams are already in memory ready to transfer out to device no more conversion required, only put inside socket.
- Tested wiht select if sending socket is ready, started monotonic, throw data inside socket, stop monotonic and see results.
- Check network with wireshark ( of 13774 send calls 13774 appear in wireshark, i count ~1310 hickups)
- Think about GIL as reason but hard to figure out.
- Turn of Firewall while testing - no change
- [Edit 1] Testet in C++ with Boost if socket can perform in target speed, here it has hickups too but they are much shorter 100-1000µs (this the 1MB buffer in device can handle)

In all tests keep in mind, the print command is only there to debug. Half of monotonic calls go to debug purpose too.

> << Removed old benchmark >> see history if need this information again!

Running on Windows 7 x64 with Python 3.4.2. @ Corei7 2630QM and 8GB RAM

> << Removed old benchmark >> see history if need this information again!

#### Edit 3

First, because I can answer it fast cProfile runs inside Thread, the _worker still is an unprofiled 2nd Thread because of low time used in waiting to be ready (~0.05 in sum) i guessed it runs fast enough. The _send function is thread entrance, and more a wrapper to be able to cProfile this Thread.

```
def _send(self):
    profile = cProfile.Profile()
    profile.enable()
    self._transfer()
    profile.disable()
    profile.print_stats()
```

Disable the Timeouts and rerun the profiling need wait 1 or 2 days i am currently cleaning up code because there still left threads in background stay in suspended state with (250ms sleeps) i think it's not a problem to let them die and respawn on usage. When this is done i will retry tests. More I think about GIL is the evil here. Possible it's the process of unpacking incomming packages within flow control and the switching between threads what can take some time and cause this hickups. (If i understand GIL correct - only one thread can execute python code at once, but i wonder why this always hits the socket action, and not split up the ready and send call in a more equal way like 40/60-50/50) So there is the futures pack on my todo list to get real multi core use with Processes. To test this out I will set the return of ready to permanent be True and the FlowControl Thread to not start or return in 1st command.

And target of this Programm is to run on Linux, Windows, Mac and Unix.

### Edit 4

First about Threads - they have no priority as mentioned here: [Controlling scheduling priority of python threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421651/controlling-scheduling-priority-of-python-threads) 
I believe there is no way to change it. The core Python runs on is at 25% max. The overall system load is around 10% when debugger runs.

The run with select was only a test. I removed the select code in send routine and tested with and without timeouts:

> << Removed old benchmark >> see history if need this information again!

#### Thread cleaned example of old code

In this example i killed all threads instead of send them sleep. And the Main thread sleeps more time.
Without FlowControl @ 5M

```
         41331 function calls in 2.935 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    2.007    2.007    2.935    2.935 SendStreamer.py:297(_transfer)
 13776    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 UDPFlowControl.py:52(ready)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method len}
 13776    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {built-in method monotonic}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
 13776    0.915    0.000    0.915    0.000 {method 'send' of '_socket.socket' objects}
```

#### With FlowControl @ 5M

Here it stays more time in waiting the device than in send.

```
            68873 function calls in 5.245 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    4.210    4.210    5.245    5.245 SendStreamer.py:297(_transfer)
 27547    0.030    0.000    0.030    0.000 UDPFlowControl.py:52(ready)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method len}
 27547    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 {built-in method monotonic}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
 13776    0.993    0.000    0.993    0.000 {method 'send' of '_socket.socket' objects}
```

Still open: split up into processes. - Still refactoring the class structures towards process usage (I think latest end of may I have some new results to add). During some more detailed benchmark I found out that the 2nd thread (unpack of VRT) takes nearly the time of each hickups duration. With processes this should no more be a possible reason to the slowdowns.

I hope there is all information required, if i forgot some please ask!

[Edit1] Added Informations in what i have done list

[Edit2] Added cProfiles of 2nd test system (Manjaro)

[Edit3] Added Informations about how cProfile runs.

[Edit4] More cProfiles + Answer about threads

[Edit5] Removed old benchmarks

Comment: Did you run cProfile per thread? Because by default cProfile only works for main thread. Also, It's not 100% clear from your `_worker` code. but do you always do select/write per packet? If so, for high throughput it's likely way more efficient to do a certain number of write calls at once (maybe even synchronous instead of async).

Comment: Because you set socket's timeout, Python adds additional `select()` before calling `send()`. Maybe it costs you extra time? Try to comment out `self.udp_socket.settimeout(self.socket_timeout)` and retry your experiments. Also, are you seriously intended to deploy network-intensive application on MS Windows?

Comment: Do your python threads run at normal priority?  One possible reason for an unexpected 1-3mS delay would be that some other thread in the OS is using the CPU core(s), and the python threads are being forced to wait until that thread's quantum is finished before they can resume executing.  In fact the described behavior sounds pretty normal for a non-real-time thread running an interpreted program in a non-real-time OS; perhaps your performance expectations are just too optimistic.  :)

Comment: "And target of this Programm is to run on Linux, Windows, Mac and Unix." I really, really feel your (coming) pain. is python mandatory here? how you are planning to distribute it? I'm 101% sure there are better tools for the task...

Comment: Yep it is mandatory. Distribution will be solved by master-project which include this. It will be packed to a stand alone executable. So you can run the entire project even without having python installed.

Comment: Can you try to use process instead threads? I don't really think that GIL is the cause, but if it is multiprocess should solve the issue.

Comment: 1. this seems like a race condition in socket.send somewhere, for debugging purpose I'd first try create the socket before `send`, do send and then close it immediately - this would reduce probability of race condition.  2. try setting better flags on created socket, like `SOCK_CLOEXEC`, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html, 3. you don't check for number of bytes sent by `send`, it should not be a problem most of the time but then... 4. try setting `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag or other flags in `send` per http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv

Comment: 5. last but not in very least, read wise words on non-blocking sockets: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets 2b. Python documentation does not say that, but if it passes `send` syscall's result as is, you might want to check if it's not -1, that's how `send` signals problems.

Comment: Re GIL: use a bunch of threads with each having its own socket, IO happens outside GIL anyway, read here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: Based on your profile, `print` overhead is almost as bad as `socket.send`, perhaps you can exclude this overhead somehow? e.g. print only when call is slower than X?

Comment: Overall, this post/comments have gotten too long, please reduce your code to minimal reproducible standalone test, basically socket creation, destination and send loop. Doable in 10~20 lines I think. Others can try t instrument your code themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this on Linux ran as unprivileged user, python2.

I don't think there's much you can do:

```
# timing code:
In [16]: @contextlib.contextmanager
   ....: def timeit():
   ....:     st = time.time()
   ....:     yield
   ....:     en = time.time()
   ....:     b = int(math.log10(en - st))
   ....:     data.setdefault(b, 0)
   ....:     data[b] += 1

# Thus, timing data means:
-6: number of times send took between 0.00000011 and 0.000001s
-4: 0.0000011 ~ 0.00001
-4: 0.000011 ~ 0.0001
-3: 0.00011 ~ 0.001 (up to millisecond)
-2: 0.0011 ~ 0.01 (1..10ms)

# Regular blocking socket
{-6: 2807, -5: 992126, -4: 5049, -3: 18}
# Non-blocking socket
{-6: 3242, -5: 991767, -4: 4970, -3: 20, -2: 1}
# socket with timeout=0
{-6: 2249, -5: 992994, -4: 4749, -3: 8}
# socket with timeout=1
{-5: 994259, -4: 5727, -3: 8, -2: 6}
```

It looks like tail of this distribution is exponential.

I also larger send buffer and adding occasional `time.sleep` to give kernel time to send our queued packet, and that didn't help. Makes sense since non-blocking also gets occasional slow send.

I also tried waiting explicitly for send queue to be empty, per http://www.pycopia.net/_modules/pycopia/socket.html `outq` function, and that didn't change the distribution either.