# How to implement synchronization in multi threading with python and ROS Services?

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore, ros

Im trying to implement multi threading (parallel processing) with python and using mutex threading. I have first process that check the Pressure Value and the modem update(in the code implemented with `odom_callback` and `callback_modem` functions), and second process that calls ROS SERVICES ( in the code implemented with  `ros_serice_server` server and `imu_client` client functions). Here is the implementation code in python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import print_function
import rospy
import numpy as np
from os import system
import time
import threading
import Microcontroller_Manager_Serial as Serial
import IMU_Functions as IMU
import Motors_Functions as Motor
import Pressure_Functions as Pressure
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3
import Modem_Functions as Modem
import threading 
import time
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
from time import sleep
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
from std_msgs.msg import String
from demo_teleop.srv import ImuValue,ImuValueResponse

P0 = 1.01325 #Default Pressure 
mutex = threading.Lock()
Communication_Mode_ = 0
pub_pressure = rospy.Publisher('depth',Vector3,queue_size=1)
pub_modem = rospy.Publisher('modem_data',Float32,queue_size=1)

def handle_ros_services(req):
    mutex.acquire(blocking=True)
    print("Server Read Data:")
    global T0
    data_received = Pressure.Pressure_Get_Final_Values(1,1)
    #print("Server Read Data:")
    T0 = (np.int16((data_received[6]<<24) | (data_received[7]<<16) | (data_received[8]<<8) | (data_received[9])))/10000
    T=T0
    temperature = T
    current_x_orientation_s = temperature
    print("Returning Service Temperature Data", current_x_orientation_s)
    return ImuValueResponse(current_x_orientation_s, True)
    mutex.release()

def ros_serice_server():
    s = rospy.Service('imu_value', ImuValue, handle_ros_services)
    print("Ready to get_value")

def odom_callback():
    # reentrang processing
    mutex.acquire(blocking=True)
    # work serial port here, e.g. send msg to serial port
    global P0
    data_received = Pressure.Pressure_Get_Final_Values(1,1)
    #P1 = (np.int16((data_received_pressure[6]<<24) | (data_received_pressure[7]<<16) | (data_received_pressure[8]<<8) | (data_received_pressure[9])))/10000
    P1 = (np.int16((data_received[6]<<24) | (data_received[7]<<16) | (data_received[8]<<8) | (data_received[9])))/10000
    #P0 = (np.int16((data_received_pressure[6]<<24) | (data_received_pressure[7]<<16) | (data_received_pressure[8]<<8) | (data_received_pressure[9])))/10000
    P0 = (np.int16((data_received[6]<<24) | (data_received[7]<<16) | (data_received[8]<<8) | (data_received[9])))/10000
    P = P0 # Relative Measured Pressure
    feedback =Vector3()
    feedback.x = 0    #Angular Velocity
    feedback.y = 0
    feedback.z = P/9.81 #Depth
    pressure = feedback.z
    print("Pressure : ", pressure)
    pub_pressure.publish(feedback)
    # reentrant processing
    mutex.release()
    
def callback_modem(event):
    # reentrant processing
    mutex.acquire(blocking=True)
    # work serial port here, e.g. check for incoming data
    event = Serial.Serial_Port_Receive_Data(20,0.2)
    if (event == 1): # Received data from acoustic modem
        modem_data= event
        pub_modem.publish(modem_data)
        print("received ")
    else:
        print("not received...... ")
    mutex.release()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialize serial port here
    Serial.Serial_Port_Standard()
    rospy.init_node('imu_value')
    ros_serice_server()
    rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(1), callback_modem) 
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            odom_callback()
        except:
            print('pass')
```

And the client node

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import print_function
import rospy
import sys
import numpy as np
from os import system
import threading
import Microcontroller_Manager_Serial as Serial
import IMU_Functions as IMU
import Motors_Functions as Motor
import Pressure_Functions as Pressure
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3
import Modem_Functions as Modem
import time
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

from time import sleep
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
from std_msgs.msg import String
from demo_teleop.srv import *

mutex = threading.Lock()
Communication_Mode_ = 0
pub_modem = rospy.Publisher('modem_data',Float32,queue_size=1)

def imu_client():
    mutex.acquire(blocking=True)
    rospy.wait_for_service('imu_value')
    imu_value = rospy.ServiceProxy('imu_value', ImuValue)
    print("Request call send")
    resp1 = imu_value(0.05)
    return resp1.current_x_orientation_s
    mutex.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node('client_node_f')
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            print("entering client")
            value = imu_client()
            print(value)
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            print('pass')
```

So the output is following. The output of the first process with the ROS Services Server is

```
Pressure :  0.10602446483180428
Server Read Data:
Returning Service Temperature Data 1.0401
```

And then after calling the client I got

```
entering client
Request call send
1.0401
entering client
```

The problem is that after calling the ROS SERVICE client node the process stop so doesn't continue with the first process (Pressure value and modem update) . The ROS SERVICES process should be call only on demand and should HALT the first process (Pressure and modem) and then is should resume with the work. So, do I need to implement SEMAPHORES for the ROS SERVICES call ? If yes how it should be in the code. So I do need kind of synchronization , right?Please any help?

Comment: Based on this application I don't believe there is really any reason that you should be uses locks at all here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
def handle_ros_services(req):
    mutex.acquire(blocking=True)
    ...
    return ImuValueResponse(current_x_orientation_s, True)
    mutex.release()
```

Because of the return statement, the release is never executed.

You need at the end:

```
    value = ImValueResponse(...)
    mutex.release()
    return value
```

Even better would be to use your mutex as part of a `with` statement:

```
with mutex:
    do anything you want, knowing that the lock will be released
    at the end, even if you return or throw an exception.
```

Comment: THANKS a lot. Let me check if that works. But, I though should use semaphores like in this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508574/semaphores-on-python  . What is the difference?

Comment: Updated my comment slightly.  You want mutual exclusion.  Seems like you want a lock.  A semaphore is more useful when you have multiple identical resources (disk drives, spaces on a bus, etc.) then when you have a single resource that only one person can use at once.   I don't completely understand your code, so I'm not sure if you should be using the same Mutex in all your functions, or if each should get its own mutex.

Comment: Sorry. Actually the first way you suggested is what I want. Semaphores is not that what I need. So thanks a lot . It works perfectly now

Comment: what do you mean by if each should get its own mutex?

Comment: Right now, you've got a single mutex that's protecting `imu_client`, `callback_modem`, and `odom_callback`.  Not only will you never have two different instances of `imu_client` running at the same time, but you will never have `imu_client` and `callback_modem` running at the same time, because they use the same mutex.  Was this your intent?  Do the three functions need protection from each other?  Or could each function use a different mutex?

Comment: I need to check exactly if these three functions need protection from each other. What happened if each function use a different mutex and how to implement that if need it?

Comment: You currently have one mutex named `mutex`.  Instead you'd create three mutexes, and each function would use acquire and release a different mutex.

Comment: I added this as a comment above, but just something to note. While this answers the question of why things aren't working, no locks are actually needed at all in OP's code.