# Start child process with limited priority

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm looking for a way how to start process with Pythons `subprocess` module with low system priority, I've already found:

- [solution for `Unix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463533/is-it-possible-to-renice-a-subprocess) using `preexec_fn` and `os.nice()`
- [`resources` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html)  which again seems only to be working for `Unix`
- [some another questions and answers for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689505/python-ulimit-and-nice-for-subprocess-call-subprocess-popen)

There's no mentioning of `priority` in [`subprocess` manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

I already have solution that seems to be working:

```
self.start_low_priority =  ('cmd', '/c', 'start', '/MIN', '/LOW', '/B', '/WAIT')
```

*NOTE:* **switches `/B /WAIT` has to be in this order for this to work**

And use it as:

```
args = self.start_low_priority + ( 'foo.exe', 'bar', 'foobar')
subprocess.call( args, shell=False)
```

But this solution doesn't seem to be the right and clean way plus [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) is unable to build correct *"Process tree"* from applications started like this (thus you don't have ability to *kill process tree*).

Is there any *good practice way* to do this for windows? Doesn't Python provide any multiplatform solution for this that I've missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`psutil`](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) library.
In particular you can set the priority setting `psutil.Process.nice` to the desired value.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245096/510937) answer for an example.

---

**Edit**: Looking at the `psutil`'s documentation setting `Process.nice` directly is deprecated, you should use `Process.nice(value)` instead.